# How to refresh an uploaded text file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to refresh an uploaded file with javascript. I already have been able to upload the text file successfully. I am having a hard time finding a way to refresh the uploaded file.

Note** The file that I am uploading is constantly being updated with information coming from a sensor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Read File (via User Input selection)</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var reader; //GLOBAL File Reader object for demo purpose only

    /**
     * Check for the various File API support.
     */
    function checkFileAPI() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser. Fallback required.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * read text input
     */
    function readText(filePath) {
        var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
        if(filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                output = e.target.result;
                displayContents(output);
            };//end onload()
            reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
        }//end if html5 filelist support
        else if(ActiveXObject && filePath) { //fallback to IE 6-8 support via ActiveX
            try {
                reader = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var file = reader.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1); //ActiveX File Object
                output = file.ReadAll(); //text contents of file
                file.Close(); //close file "input stream"
                displayContents(output);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.number == -2146827859) {
                    alert('Unable to access local files due to browser security settings. ' +
                     'To overcome this, go to Tools->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level. ' +
                     'Find the setting for "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" and change it to "Enable" or "Prompt"');
                }
            }
        }
        else { //this is where you could fallback to Java Applet, Flash or similar
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * display content using a basic HTML replacement
     */
    function displayContents(txt) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main');
        el.innerHTML = txt; //display output in DOM
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkFileAPI();">
    <div id="container">
        <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <h3>Contents of the Text file:</h3>
        <div id="main">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

after loading the file, content of the file should be constantly updating and showing the updated results on the web page

Comment: Where does it fail? Do you get a value in `displayContents(output);`?

Comment: I am able to upload the file with no errors. The displayContents(output) does display the current content of the file. With the file I am uploading, I am constantly saving the file and I am trying to show the constantly updated text file to the webpage.

Comment: Ah, so you want to read it in a loop, with a timer?

Comment: In a way. I basically want to show "Live" data from the text file that holds sensor data (which is just a single number in the text file which gets updated depending on how close you get to the sensor)

Comment: You might want to make yourself a little app using Node, which can watch files and run JS automatically. Then you can skip the whole upload step.

See: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener